# jQuery cycle plugin how to add an active class

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

example: http://jsfiddle.net/kuTLf/

code looks like this:

```
<div id="main">
        <div id="slideshow" class="pics">
            <div id="nav"></div>
            <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
            <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach2.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
            <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach3.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(function() {
    $('#slideshow').cycle({
        fx:     'turnDown',
        speed:  'fast',
        timeout: 3000,
        pager:  '#nav',
        slideExpr: 'img'
    });
});
```

How can I add current active class to current img? like `<img class='active`>

Comment: It might be easier to inspect the DOM with the developer tools to see if Cycle already adds a special `class` to the active item.  If so, just use that instead of adding your own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({
    after: function(el, next_el) {
        $(next_el).addClass('active');
    },
    before: function(el) {
        $(el).removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KqN9K/1/) to know which is active.

```
function onAfter1(curr,next,opts) {
   currentSlide = $(".thePager a.activeSlide").html();
    if(!currentSlide) currentSlide = "1";
    $('.slideCaption').html(currentSlide + '/' + opts.slideCount);
}
```